# Method in Typescript does not compile because of Index Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Lets say I want to define this method in Typescript:

```
setResult(guId: string,fieldname: string, data:Array<UsedTsoClusterKey>) {
  let octdctruns: OctDctRun[] = [...this.octDctRuns];
  const index = octdctruns.findIndex((o) => o.guid === guId);
  octdctruns[index][fieldname] = data;
  this.octDctRuns = octdctruns;
}
```

UsedTsoClusterKey and OctDctRun looks like this:

```
export interface UsedTsoClusterKey {
  runGUID: string;
  tsoClusterKeyID: string;
  tsoClusterKeyVersion: string;
  validFrom: DateString;
  validUntil: DateString;
}

export interface OctDctRun {
  guid: string;
  moduleType: string;
  runTime: DateString;
  calcIntervalFrom: DateString;
  calcIntervalUntil: DateString;
  triggerType: string;
  triggerID: string;
  usedTSOClusterKeys: UsedTsoClusterKey[];
}
```

But im getting an error for the line *octdctruns[index][fieldname] = data*:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'OctDctRun'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'OctDctRun'
```

I do not understand the problem here. Please help!

Comment: You cannot use `string` as a key of `OctDctRun`, too broad. Anyway, only the field `usedTSOClusterKeys` can be assigned to `UsedTsoClusterKey[]`, so why is it a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know that `fieldName` is a property of `OctDctRun`, furthermore, it wouldn't know that `data` is assignable to the property that you're addressing with `fieldName`. The other answer provided does give a solution for this, albeit a bit specific to your use-case. However, there is a much more dynamic way to do this that doesn't require hardcoding the type for `data`:

```js
class Test {
    setResult<FieldName extends keyof OctDctRun>(guId: string, fieldName: FieldName, data: OctDctRun[FieldName]) {
        let octdctruns = [...this.octDctRuns];
        const index = octdctruns.findIndex((o) => o.guid === guId);
        octdctruns[index][fieldName] = data;
        this.octDctRuns = octdctruns;
    }
}
```

If you use a generic `FieldName` that must be a key of `OctDctRun`, and then say that the argument `fieldName` must be of that type, and then say that `data` must then be a value that is assignable to that `fieldName`, you get 100% type safety 100% of the time.

Here's a playground [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsCBlYAnAlgOwOZQLxQDOaW2A3AFAVaKoBmcAxtAKqEQAmAKoQPYDCAGwCuxCKgDSEEFADeFKFFTDMAcRYBJGAC4iJHJUXA%20Q0bSkgtu4hgMKoxgSLGTpANXGF0vTNf3l7ADc4QXQOADFUXgBbXXhEFFsAxWDQjhZMYHRBOIRkf0oAXyoacQZmKAB5RmAYGoAlFTl7bGEwvyTDKGjeDmFBCC5wCA7SLuVMLnRokdg8xLH7RhDGDUzxVMiY3ISCpZW12lSMrJy53c77EmxscSHIUbsjDBvxKz1LxVFOLiRK0xcFkIujYPxMznM0gA2gBdIpURiCOCEQhQLgQYjNRSKXg1OrARqYYFVPENFSw-BQWGUeyKdgEjH9YAAHnC6Aggg4ADk4DMoBAAB6ITAcVEAa2kvDoJNqZMwAD4ABStDQcR7YAA0dHZnMwvNmbI53P1GqgHAQcF01VlBPJhs5PJmMIAlFjse6BsAoLjgBwahNUQQoQA6UPAAAW6EIwZ9%20MJhDhtPdUEYPkxWA4gspPr9aBU0e1IrWmYFisVvFdeHl3uDrTC%20DwBBVHGdXWT3pquYDUIzgphUO1Rr1Tsp5uAcDbyYjUZjpNtROznf9%20cnxUKQA)

Answer (score 1):

`fieldname: keyof OctDctRun` - this will fix your current issue, but here is another issue: `data` is an array of `UsedTsoClusterKey` entities, so it can be assign only to `usedTSOClusterKeys` according to your type defenition. So the proper type defenition will be like so: `keyof Pick<OctDctRun, 'usedTSOClusterKeys'>`, but I'm not sure if it covers your case ¯_(ツ)_/¯